# In Angular Material what does setting up global typography styles mean?

Tags: angular-material

When using `ng add @angular/material` to add Material support to an Angular project there is a prompt `Set up global Angular Material typography styles?`

What does this even mean? The documentation states the prompt appears, but does not describe what it actually means.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

By default, Angular Material doesn’t apply global CSS. Meaning that a standard element (eg. `<h1>`) will not have Angular materials' styles applied to it.
So, when configured this way, in order to apply Angular material styles to a broad section of your HTML, you can use the `mat-typography` class

```html
<h1>This header doesn't have Angular Material styling</h1>
<section class="mat-typography">
<h1>This header does have Angular Material styling</h1>
</section>
```

If you set up global typography styles; then the first `<h1>` will already be styled.

Comment: +1. This information should have been included in [Angular Material's getting started document](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Comment: If anyone wants to change this after the project already was created, simply add the class="mat-typography" to the body of the index.html. That is just the same thing as the angular cli does, at this moment at least.
More in detail info can be found in the [Angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography).